# Referencing symbols in other files using PPC assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler, powerpc

How can you reference a symbol external to the current file in ppc assembly? I've tried looking at the .extern keyword as well as adding a new symbol in the linker file but with no success.

I have two ppc assembly files that are part of a larger project. I wish to reference a symbol (__head) in file1 from file2 in this way:

file1.S:

```
    .section ".head","ax"

    . = 0
.global __head
__head:
```

file2.S:

```
    .section ".head","ax"
...
    LOAD_32(%r3, file2_symbol_name - __head)
```

where LOAD_32 is

```
#define LOAD_32(r, e)           \
    lis     r,(e)@h;            \
    ori     r,r,(e)@l;
```

...but am getting the following error:

```
file2.S: Assembler messages:
file2.S:113: Error: can't resolve `file2_symbol_name' {.head section} - `__head' {*UND* section}
file2.S:113: Error: expression too complex
```

When used in file1 `LOAD_32(%r3, file1_symbol_name - __head)` works just fine so I know I'm not importing the symbol name correctly.  How can I do this?

EDIT:

I have reduced my problem to the bare minimum parts so that I am clear about the problem. Below is all of the code, linker file, Makefile, and the terminal output for "make quick".

**NB:** When I comment out line 9 of other.S the project compiles without error.

head.S:

```
#include "asm-defines.h"

    .section ".head","ax"
    .align 0x10

    . = 0x0

.global __head
__head:
    LOAD_32(%r3, file1_symbol_name - __head)
    b   .

file1_symbol_name:
    b   .
```

other.S

```
#include "asm-defines.h"

    .section ".head","ax"
    .align 0x10

.global other
other:
    LOAD_32(%r3, file2_symbol_name)
    LOAD_32(%r3, file2_symbol_name - __head)
    b   .

file2_symbol_name:
    b   .
```

asm-defines.h:

```
#ifndef ASM_DEFINES_H
#define ASM_DEFINES_H

/* Load an immediate 32-bit value into a register */
#define LOAD_32(r, e)           \
    lis     r,(e)@h;            \
    ori     r,r,(e)@l;      

#endif //ASM_DEFINES_H
```

quick.lds

```
ENTRY(__head);
```

Makefile

```
CC=$(CROSS)gcc
QFLAGS := -Wl,--oformat,elf64-powerpc -pie -m64 -mbig-endian -nostdlib

quick:
    $(CC) $(QFLAGS) -T quick.lds head.S other.S -o quick.o
```

$(CROSS) is a path to the cross compiler which I have omitted.
The CC is powerpc64le-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc

Terminal

```
$ make quick
powerpc64le-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc -Wl,--oformat,elf64-powerpc -pie -m64 -mbig-endian -nostdlib -T quick.lds head.S other.S -o quick.o
other.S: Assembler messages:
other.S:9: Error: can't resolve `.head' {.head section} - `__head' {*UND* section}
other.S:9: Error: expression too complex
other.S:9: Error: can't resolve `.head' {.head section} - `__head' {*UND* section}
other.S:9: Error: expression too complex
make: *** [quick] Error 1
```

Comment: what assembler is this? gnu assembler?  (the program which then defines the language)

Comment: Yes, it's gnu. This part I believe I need to do in assembly. I'm making code that will patch the system reset interrupt vector and I will have lost all of my register values including the TOC pointer when at this vector.

Comment: Ah, well I guess I'm doing assembly but it's running through the preprocessor first. It's defined as a **.S** file which I believe gcc treats as "Assembler code which must be preprocessed." Thus using the #define works fine. I believe the error is specifically related to the reference to `- __head` seeing as `LOAD_32(%r3, file2_symbol_name)` compiles fine in file2, as does `LOAD_32(%r3, file1_symbol_name - __head)` in file1.

That said, it is assembly... so I don't think the #include could help me with the external reference here if you're suggesting including a c-function descriptor.

Comment: either I dont understand the question or I solved it and tested it on two different backends in roughly 3-5 minutes, wasnt timing it...both an assembly solution and a C syntax solution.

Comment: @old_timer It would be great if you did indeed solve it. I have edited my post above to include simplified code of the problem which I have verified produces the same error condition. Further if I comment out line 9 of other.S the project compiles fine despite line 8 of other.S and line 10 of head.S. I am looking for a way to reference `__head` from other.S in such a situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembler cannot know the placement / relative position of head.S and other.S at assembly time to be able to compute the relative displacement of the file2_symbol_name and __head labels.  This is a general assembly language question, not PPC specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had thought that it would try going through a linking stage before complaining about an issue like this, but I guess that isn't the case

Answer (score 1):

Regarding David's response, see https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Infix-Ops.html#Infix-Ops, where it specifies:  "Subtraction. If the right argument is absolute, the result has the section of the left argument. If both arguments are in the same section, the result is absolute. You may not subtract arguments from different sections."  The error message indicates that the assembler has no idea which section contains __head, which indeed it cannot, since the symbol and its section are not defined in filescope.

You might be able to get what you want by using the .weak and/or .weakref directives so that the symbol can be defined in two files, with the strong reference overriding the weak one at link time.  I haven't experimented with this.  See the manual (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) and hunt for .weak.

Some background information on weak symbols is here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol.

Comment: Thanks so much for your addition! So even though I used `.section ".head"` in both files they aren't considered as part of the same "section" until linking?